# How to construct a Currency Locale from a String?

Tags: java, locale, currency, number-formatting

How does one get a Locale from a String containing both characters and numberals? Is it even possible? I'm not terribly advanced in java, and I'm afraid this is getting into the deeper end of the figurative pool.

Say I have;

```
String userInput = "250.00 SEK";
```

From this I want to device the means to print "Sweden".
So all I know is the currency code, and I'm wanting the DisplayName for that locale.

Comment: If the format is relatively the same, you can regexp to split the String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all currencies have 3 characters (http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php) you could just

```
    String code = userInput.substring(userInput.length()-3,userInput.length());
    state = Currency.valueOf(code);
    system.out.print(state.name);


public enum Currency{
  SEK("Sweden"),
  GBP("British Pound");

  private String name;

  public Currency(String n) { this.name = n; }
  public String toString() { return this.name; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your only hope is to build a `Map<String, Locale>` by hand and do lookups based on the country code at the end of your currency string. There is no automated way to go from a currency to a locale (at least that I am aware of)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getAvailableCurrencies%28%29) class in combination with the codes used in [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

Answer (score 0):

```
String userInput = "250.00 SEK";
    final Set<Currency> availableCurrencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
    for (Currency availableCurrency : availableCurrencies) {
        final String currencyCode = availableCurrency.getCurrencyCode();
        final String displayName = availableCurrency.getDisplayName();
        if (userInput.contains(currencyCode)){
            System.out.println("Currency is " + availableCurrency.getDisplayName());
        }
    }
```

Currency is Swedish Krona

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your string will always have space in it you can split it by space and then get currency instance by the second value in the returned array.

```
String userInput = "250.00 SEK";
String[] parts = userInput.split(" ");

Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(parts[1]);

System.out.print(currency.getDisplayName());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String userInput = "250.00 SEK";
    final Set<Currency> availableCurrencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
    for (Currency availableCurrency : availableCurrencies) {
        final String strCode = availableCurrency.getCurrencyCode();
        final String currencyCode = strCode;
        if (userInput.contains(currencyCode)){
            for (Locale locale : NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
                String code = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
                if (strCode.equals(code)) {
                    System.out.println(locale.getDisplayCountry());;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Will give you: Sweden